# Block images in UIWebView by domain name

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I would like to stop a `UIWebView` from loading specific images. The problem is that, although the images change, the domain name stays the same; for example, `adsmarket.com`.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://network.adsmarket.com/click/imVtnmGcqZWQaWmcX8p8mItoasReyoCYj2JylV_Kf5qMYnLEYaB6lomQbJdknnqV">
    <img width="728" height="90" border="0" src="http://network.adsmarket.com/stc/35021/6471901/ctv.png">
</a>
```

I want this blocked IN the `UIWebView`, and no, I can't edit the page's HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should try looking at this answer.  [Rob's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586930/iphone-sdk-uiwebview-to-stop-images-from-loading-downloading) (and a subsequent answer that expands on it) won't be trivial to implement, but is doable.

Or, check out this [other answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602906/119114).  In this one, yonel suggests implementing your own `NSURLCache`.  When one of the images from adsmarket.com is requested, you would return an image from your cache (which could be a dummy image ... maybe clear or 1x1 pixel), instead of letting the request go to the real adsmarket.com server.  The cached image would just be something local, bundled in your app, not a remote image.

Comment: Or use an NSURLProtocol derived class to intercept the calls on only allow certain ones to proceed. Also courtesy of Rob Napier: http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588